# How to use nested inline templates in ASP.NET MVC Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to nest templates in the Razor view-engine such 
like this in the older Asp.net viewengine? For as much as i am aware Razor only supports one level of templates.

-John

```
   <%Html.Do(new string[]{"Chris","John"}, name =>
    { 
        %>

        <li><%=name%></li>

        <%Html.Do(new string[]{"Beer","Fries"}, stuff => { 
            %>
            <li><%=stuff%></li>
            <% 
        }); %>

        <hr size=1 />

        <% 
    }
); %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your function to take a `Func<T, HelperResult>`, then pass `@<li>@item</li>`

**EDIT**: For example:

```
public static IHtmlString Do<T>(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, HelperResult> template) {
    return html.Raw(String.Join("\n", items.Select(o => template(o).ToString())));
}
```

In Razor:

```
@Html.Do(new []{"Beer","Fries"}, @<li>@item</li>)
```

Comment: @user: Sorry; I meant `HelperResult`.  Here's an example.

Comment: where is the code example you refer to in the comment?
The example above uses just 1 level...the problem comes when the first in-line template contains a method that in turn contains another in line template. Then Razor triggers an error saying nested templates are not allowed. Do you know a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: @FrancescoAbbruzzese: No; Razor does not support nested inline helpers (the implicit parameters would conflict).  You could move the content of the outer inline helper to a normal helper.

Comment: Sincerely..I don't understand why they put this limitation....I don't think the conflict of the "item" implicit parameter is the reason. The name conflict might have been handled with the usual "scoping" rules...ie the the "item" is scoped with the innermost level it is in...also VS intellisense is able to understand scoping...so it might give the right suggestions on "item".

Comment: @FrancescoAbbruzzese: No; that would not compile.  (try it)  The Razor transformer is not connected to the C# parser, so that wouldn't be so easy to work around.    See also [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/search/label/dissecting-razor).

Comment: I know that nested in line helpers do not compile. I read your blog but there I have not found an explication of why the name conflict cannot be solved...In my experience such scoping problems can be solved by using a stack to represent the several values of the conflicting names. The Razor compiler might handle the nested templates by using a stack to store the current scope....No need to be connected with th C# compiler. When I'll have nore time I'll give a look to the sources...At moment I solved my problem by defining begin-end extension methods to create a new scope

Comment: @FrancescoAbbruzzese: That would be confusing; since the names aren't declared in source, it would not be obvious what each name is.

Comment: This might be a reason....however why don't let the choice to the developer? there might have introduced also a keyword like 'parent' to refers tobthe item in th level up. The templwte engine in thle js knockout library do this way.